# Facebook desktop application access token

Tags: facebook, token, secret-key

i'm developing a desktop solution ( c# ),that can access facebook throuhgh facebook sdk .NET, actually I can't understand how to obtain an access token using the facebook  sdk or graph api, any suggestion ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

i got it, hope can be helpful :)

```
 client = new FacebookClient();

        try
        {

            dynamic getOuth = client.Get("oauth/access_token", new
            {
                client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                grant_type = "client_credentials",
                redirect_uri="https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"

            });

            token = getOuth.access_token.ToString();


        }
```

Comment: Can you explain the step, how you do that? Because I am facing the same issue.